# Why is there a seemingly useless infinite for loop in the main function in src/runtime/proc.go?

Tags: go, runtime

Today I came across a post asking about this question. At the end of the main function in `src/runtime/proc.go` there is a seemingly useless infinite for loop. Why is it there?

[source code link](https://golang.org/src/runtime/proc.go)

```golang
    if atomic.Load(&panicking) != 0 {
        gopark(nil, nil, waitReasonPanicWait, traceEvGoStop, 1)
    }

    exit(0)
    for {
        var x *int32
        *x = 0
    }
```

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/golang-nuts/FnF3oZeJ7aY

Comment: Linking groups from mobile is incredibly hard, here's the proper link: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/FnF3oZeJ7aY/sLz0G3oDAgAJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning `0` to a protected memory region e.g. [`*(*int)(nil) = 0`](https://play.golang.org/p/QSoW9RMd3Ur) and [`*x = 0`](https://play.golang.org/p/qgRF_269gCg) in systems with [memory protection unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection_unit) causes [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) and stops the programme,
And in systems without memory protection unit, just writes `0` to the memory address at zero and nothing happens so they added a for loop to stop the programme (CPU) there.

1. Normally it is (should be) **unreachable code**.
2. File: `~/go/src/runtime/proc.go` at the end of `func main()`:

```
    exit(0)
    for {
        var x *int32
        *x = 0
    }
```

[ref](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/FnF3oZeJ7aY/sLz0G3oDAgAJ):

> The runtime is a special case in many ways, and this is among the more
>   special parts.  This loop exists to catch problems while testing new 
>   ports.  If that loop is ever reached, something has gone badly wrong: 
>   the exit call should have caused the program to exit.  We can't assume
>   that panic is working.  We can't really assume that anything is 
>   working.  What we want to do is stop the program.  Since exit failed, 
>   it's possible that a nil dereference will succeed.  If that fails too,
>   we still have to do something, so we just loop.  We can't return 
>   because this is the main function that started the program; there is 
>   nothing to return to.

---

3. Also Calling `panic("err msg")` here inside `/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go` at the end of `func fatalpanic(msgs *_panic)` has **unreachable code**:

```
    systemstack(func() {
        exit(2)
    })

    *(*int)(nil) = 0 // not reached
}
```

---

4. Here `var x *int`: `x` is a `nil` pointer, so `*x = 0` is a panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference and causes segmentation violation:

```
package main

func main() {
    var x *int
    *x = 0
}
```

Output:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x44f972]
```

---

5. Here for test propose to generated a panic and recover:
   File `~/go/src/internal/x/crypto/cryptobyte/cryptobyte_test.go`

```
func TestGeneratedPanic(t *testing.T) {
    defer func() {
        recover()
    }()

    var b Builder
    b.AddUint8LengthPrefixed(func(b *Builder) {
        var p *byte
        *p = 0
    })

    t.Error("Builder did not panic")
}
```

---

6. File `~/go/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/subr.go`:

```
func hcrash() {
    if Debug['h'] != 0 {
        flusherrors()
        if outfile != "" {
            os.Remove(outfile)
        }
        var x *int
        *x = 0
    }
}
```

7. File `~/go/pkg/bootstrap/src/bootstrap/cmd/compile/internal/gc/subr.go`:

```
func hcrash() {
    if Debug['h'] != 0 {
        flusherrors()
        if outfile != "" {
            os.Remove(outfile)
        }
        var x *int
        *x = 0
    }
}
```

Which is called here `~/go/src/cmd/compile/internal/gc/subr.go` at the end of:

```
func Fatalf(fmt_ string, args ...interface{}) {
    flusherrors()

    if Debug_panic != 0 || nsavederrors+nerrors == 0 {
        fmt.Printf("%v: internal compiler error: ", linestr(lineno))
        fmt.Printf(fmt_, args...)
        fmt.Printf("\n")

        // If this is a released compiler version, ask for a bug report.
        if strings.HasPrefix(objabi.Version, "go") {
            fmt.Printf("\n")
            fmt.Printf("Please file a bug report including a short program that triggers the error.\n")
            fmt.Printf("https://golang.org/issue/new\n")
        } else {
            // Not a release; dump a stack trace, too.
            fmt.Println()
            os.Stdout.Write(debug.Stack())
            fmt.Println()
        }
    }

    hcrash()
    errorexit()
}
```

---

8. Following code panics here inside `/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go` at the end of `func fatalpanic(msgs *_panic)`:

```
    systemstack(func() {
        exit(2)
    })

    *(*int)(nil) = 0 // not reached
}
```

[Code to panic!](https://play.golang.org/p/QnG9cTVsZ-8) (similar to Calling `panic("err msg")`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

func main() {
    r := rand.Rand{}
    i := r.Int()
    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

Output:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0xffffffff addr=0x0 pc=0xd8276]

goroutine 1 [running]:
math/rand.(*Rand).Int63(...)
    /usr/local/go/src/math/rand/rand.go:85
math/rand.(*Rand).Int(...)
    /usr/local/go/src/math/rand/rand.go:103
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox449835614/main.go:10 +0x36
```